# intel xdk converting base64 into a local image

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, appframework

So this is the path I would like to take.

Step 1) Server returns base64 of an image

Step 2) phone app converts base64 to an image

Step 3) phone app saves image to phone

Step 4) Use cordova app to get image's file URI

I can already do Step 1 and step 4. My issue is trying to take the base64 and converting it into an image on the phone. I am aware that I could use the base64 in the source of an image tag to SHOW the image but this will not work for me. I need a file URI to use with the cordova upload call (sending base64 to this call works in android but not in iOS).

Any help would be appreciated. Merry belated Christmas everyone!! :)

**Update**:

Ive been trying to download the image instead of receiving the base64 response in order to provide the upload method with a valid file uri instead of the base64:

```
        var uri = encodeURI("<my_server>/public/assets/uploads/img_54a2b5b29912b.jpg");
        var fileURL = "/sdcard/testCordova/file.png";
        var ft = new FileTransfer();  
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();            
        var headers={'Authorization':authHeader};
        ft.download(
            uri,
            fileURL,
            function(entry) {
                alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("download error source " + error.source);
                alert("download error target " + error.target);
                alert("upload error code" + error.code);
            },
            true,
            options
        );
```

This keeps on returning an error code = 3 on android (haven't tested on iOS). Still stuck.

Comment: If you show the dataurl as an image in a canvas, you might be able to save it as a file.  There are some possibilities here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement - (toDataURL, toBlob).  Not sure if that's quite what you need, but if you can get a Blob you should be able to write it to a file, I thnk.